# Powershell - Retrieve values from Azure (az) commands

Tags: azure, powershell

I'm trying to write a simple script to retrieve a key value from Azure Storage account. Below is the code:

```
az login
az account set --subscription 1111-222-3333-444-55555555


$azure_blob_login = "teststorage123"
$azure_blob_access_key = az storage account keys list --account-name $azure_blob_login


Write-Output $azure_blob_access_key
Write-Output $azure_blob_access_key[0]
```

The output from the first write-output is:

```
[
  {
    "creationTime": "2022-02-23T06:45:00.085500+00:00",
    "keyName": "key1",
    "permissions": "FULL",
    "value": "11111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111"
  },
  {
    "creationTime": "2022-02-23T06:45:00.085500+00:00",
    "keyName": "key2",
    "permissions": "FULL",
    "value": "22222222222222222222222222222222222222222222"
  }
]
```

However the output from the second write-output where I am trying to index to just get the first value in the array is just:
[

Anyone know how I can return the value from this az command and only get the first "value" entry from the first entry in the array?

Thanks,

Comment: @Gaurav Mantri - Posted the answer without checking the previous one. Will delete it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The default output from Az cli is JSON.

If you want to create an array of properties you would have to convert the az cli output to a psobject

```
$keys = $azure_blob_access_key | ConvertFrom-Json
$keys[0]
```